# ASP.NET - is ReportViewer control available in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Ive seen some gerat things about the "ReportViewer" control in Visual studio. Is this actually available in Visual Studio 2008? I can't find it. 
If not, is there an alternative? If so, anyone knwo any decent tutorials on them?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have downloaded and installed the Report Viewer control.

Right click in the Database section, and select choose items. 
It will bring up a dialog of items that can be added.
Find ReportViewer and select betweeen Winformsor WebForms.